# ERROR [karma]: { inspect: [Function: inspect] } while ng test on my Mac

Tags: angular, google-chrome, jasmine, karma-runner

I will appreciate any help...
I'm trying to run my Unit Test (*Karma/Jasmin*) on a **Mac** where my local development environment is installed.
I'm facing an issue while attempting to run **ng test**
this is the error I get **ERROR [karma]: { inspect: [Function: inspect] }**
The chrome is opening but 10s later it crashes.

[image: my terminal console]

this is my karma.conf.js[image: karma.conf.js]

[image: package.json dev dependencies]

Comment: Any chance you are running this on an Apple Silicon (M1) processor? I see you are running an older version of Karma (2.0.0). I believe these had problems with the M1.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem.  Nothing was wrong with my code.  Firstly, make sure you have the proper node version (you're not too far ahead or behind).

Then I restarted my IDE.  I use Visual Studio Code.  After banging my head for 2 hours trying to fix this, I gave up for the night and came back the next morning.  Opened everything up, restarted VS Code and it was working like a charm.

Answer (score -1):

I tried updating the Karma version from 2.0.0 to 6.3.17 and it works for me.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33547132)

Comment: This solution fixed my issue also.